# env.local doesnt work in my NextJS Project

Tags: next.js

I am storing some database credentials in `.env.local` file in root directory. When I run my project it says `DB_URL` is required. I am referencing their official documentation. I am using it on my Linux machine.

Comment: Can you post your env file?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and getting annoyed. I restarted the vs-code several times. Meanwhile, my error vanished. lol

if you have coded this way eg-`(process.env.DB_URL);` 
Then simple just restart your ide/editor. If didn't work just double check your code.

All the best. Hope you get rid of your bug

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding `.env` variables in `next.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    DB_URL: "your_url"
  }
}
```